# Get column value of repeating table?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this table:

```js
var table = document.getElementById('tableID'),
    cells = table.getElementsByTagName('td');

for (var x = 0, len = cells.length; x < len; x++) {
    cells[x].onclick = function () {
        console.log(this.innerHTML);
    };
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped" id="tableID">
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="cup in cups">
          <td>{{cup.cupnum}}</td>
          <td>{{::cup.contents.model}}</td>
          <td>{{::cup.contents.woa}}</td>
          <td>{{::cup.contents.perfBy}}</td>
          <td>{{::cup.contents.perfAt}}</td>
          <td>{{::cup.contents.loadEvent}}</td>
          <td>{{samples[cup.contents.sampleID-1].contents.name}}</td>
          <td>{{holders[cup.contents.holderID-1].contents.type}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I make it so that i'm just getting the value of the last column for each row without having to click? The: `<td>{{holders[cup.contents.holderID-1].contents.type}}</td>`
column

Comment: You have all the data in `cups` array. Map and get array of last collumns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use:

```
cells =  table.querySelector('td:last-child')
```

This will always return the last td of the rows.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To access the last columns, query all `td:last-child`

```js
var cells = document.querySelectorAll('#tableID td:last-child');
var result = document.getElementById("result");
result.innerHTML="";
for (var x = 0, len = cells.length; x < len; x++) {
        result.innerHTML+=cells[x].innerHTML+"<br>";
};
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped" id="tableID" border="1">
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="cup in cups">
          <td>{{cup.cupnum}}</td>
          <td>{{::cup.contents.model}}</td>
          <td>{{::cup.contents.woa}}</td>
          <td>{{::cup.contents.perfBy}}</td>
          <td>{{::cup.contents.perfAt}}</td>
          <td>{{::cup.contents.loadEvent}}</td>
          <td>{{samples[cup.contents.sampleID-1].contents.name}}</td>
          <td>{{holders[cup.contents.holderID-1].contents.type}}</td>
      </tr>
       <tr ng-repeat="cup in cups">
          <td>{{cup.cupnum}}</td>
          <td>{{::cup.contents.model}}</td>
          <td>{{::cup.contents.woa}}</td>
          <td>{{::cup.contents.perfBy}}</td>
          <td>{{::cup.contents.perfAt}}</td>
          <td>{{::cup.contents.loadEvent}}</td>
          <td>{{samples[cup.contents.sampleID-1].contents.name}}</td>
          <td>{{holders[cup.contents.holderID-1].contents.type}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<hr>
<h2>Result</h2>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!